# How to Find Longest Distance b/w char in String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, logic

```
public class LongestAlphabetDistance {

    public int longDistance(String str, String a) {
        str = "this is my greatest achievement in the world";
        a = "i";
        int count =0;
        // code logic for longest difference
        return count;
    }
}
```

I want to get "this is my greatest achievement in the world" distance b/w first 
`a = i` and last i like `t=1,h=2,i=3,s=4,` space should not count than `i=5,s=6,m=7,y=8,g=9` like that last `i` "in" `i=27` so first `i=3` last `i=27` so longest distance `b/w` 24 kindly write a code for that

Comment: can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework

Comment: SO is for asking questions not for doing your work!

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't even understand the question to be honest. Should the program just count the amount of characters in the `String` (minus spaces) or some distance between characters? There is also a typo, it should be achi`e`vement.

Comment: Homework or not, it looks like a code writing request to me, such are not popular on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LongestAlphabetDistance {

    public int longDistance(String str, String a) {
        str = "this is my greatest achivement in the world";
        a = "i";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        char[] chArray = str.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Integer> inArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i =0;i<chArray.length;i++) {
            if(chArray[i] == a.charAt(0) ) {
                inArray.add(i+1);
            }
        }

        return inArray.get(inArray.size()-1)-inArray.get(0); // 24 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`indexOf`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to get the first index of your char, and [**`lastIndexOf`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) to get the last index, for example :

```
String str = "this is my greatest achivement in the world";
String a = "i";

int indexFirst = str.replace(" ", "").indexOf(a);//this return 2
int indexLast = str.replace(" ", "").lastIndexOf(a);//this return 26

int dist = indexLast - indexFirst; //this return 24
```

---

**Note** this two methods `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` start from 0, for that you get 2 and 24 instead of 3 and 27

Answer (score 0):

With correct spelling, the distance is 25:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "this is my greatest achievement in the world".replaceAll(" ", "");
        String a = "i";
        int firstI = str.indexOf(a);
        int lastI = str.lastIndexOf(a);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d", str, "First i: ", firstI, "Last i: ", lastI, "Distance: ", (lastI - firstI));

    }
```

**Output:**

```
thisismygreatestachievementintheworld
First i: 2
Last i: 27
Distance: 25
```